# I am trying to convert the image to binary format and then return it to bmp format, however, the image turns out to be different

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Using the pillow library, as well as my own function that translates an image from the ".bmp" format to a list of rgb colors, I am trying to recreate a ".bmp" image, but the image is obtained at an angle, and also has a diagonal black stripe that goes from the lower left to the upper right at an angle of 45 degrees.

```
from PIL import Image

def read_bmp_pixels_rgb(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as bmp_file:
        binary_data = bmp_file.read()

    pixel_data = []
    for i in range(122, len(binary_data), 3):
        r, g, b = binary_data[i], binary_data[i + 1], binary_data[i + 2]
        r_bits = format(r, '08b')
        g_bits = format(g, '08b')
        b_bits = format(b, '08b')
        pixel_data.append([r_bits, g_bits, b_bits])

    return pixel_data

def create_image_from_pixels(pixel_data, width, height,file_path):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
    pixels = img.load()

    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            r, g, b = pixel_data[y * width + x]
            pixels[x, height - y - 1] = (int(r, 2), int(g, 2), int(b, 2))
    img.save(file_path)


path = "28.bmp"
a=read_bmp_pixels_rgb(path)

width = 431
height = 378
output_file_path = 'output.bmp'
create_image_from_pixels(a, width, height, output_file_path)
```

I know that bmp images contain the first 122 bits of service information and also, my file uses 8-bit color encoding.

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIF7Q.png)

What can help me in this situation?

Comment: Why are you trying to decode a .bmp file yourself when PIL can do it easily?  There are a lot of details to attend to if you're going to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is 431 pixels wide but BMP lines are padded up to the nearest multiple of 4.

Try reading a line of 431 RGB pixels from your BMP then reading and discarding one extra 3-byte RGB pixel of padding before starting the next line.